# Calculating duration of a section with knowledge of mid-point of consecutive sections

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Having a brain freeze on this, I have a nagging suspicion this is very straightforward but can't see it and attempts thus far have produced nothing.

There are say, $n$ items of duration $x_1, x_2, x_3$ etc. We know the time of the midpoint of each item, is it possible to algebraically calculate the length of a section with knowledge of the midpoint of adjacent sections alone, if so how many adjacent sections is it necessary to have knowledge of? We do not know the start time or end time of any item, only the midpoint.

So: Section 1, midpoint = 8s. Section 2, midpoint = 28s. Section 3, midpoint = 36s. Section 4, midpoint = 50s.

What is the methodology to calculate duration of Section $x$?